# Caddy web server and Flash file

Tags: flash, webserver, caddy

When I ask for a flash file like http://www.example.com/test.swf on my Caddy server (http://caddyserver.com/), browsers start to download it instead of opening it.

How to set up Caddy so flash file (*.swf) could be directly opened by browser. I think I need to define Mime type on the server side in Caddyfile. What parameter should I set?

Comment: Good news, [we're adding custom mime types](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/pull/259) in the next version

Answer (score 1):

By default, Caddy sends binary files as `application/octet-stream` which, in most clients, triggers a download. You want it to be `application/x-shockwave-flash`.

#### With Caddy 0.8+

Add this to your Caddyfile:

```
mime .swf application/x-shockwave-flash
```

(Thanks to the comment reminding me to update this answer.)

#### Old Answer:

Add this to your Caddyfile (assuming all .swf content is in a folder called flash):

```
header /flash Content-Type application/x-shockwave-flash
```

This sets the Content-Type for all files in /flash to the more correct value ([header directive docs](https://caddyserver.com/docs/header)). In a future version of Caddy we'll probably have a way of customizing MIME types. (**Update**: Now we do!)

Comment: The feature is now available here. [https://caddyserver.com/docs/mime](https://caddyserver.com/docs/mime)